# ¿Cómo recuperar documentos almacenados en base de datos?

Tags: c#, sql, blob

Tengo una base de datos donde existen documentos, el contenido está en un campo 
`VARBINARY(MAX)`. Mi duda es, ¿cómo puedo generar el documento en alguna carpeta?

He empezado por este código que se encuentra en esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa/26304129#26304129)

```
public static byte[] StringToByteArray(String hex)
{
    int NumberChars = hex.Length;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2)
        bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
    return bytes;
}
```

Pero estoy teniendo problemas ya que el String que le mando es demasiado largo, es proveniente de un `VARBINARY(MAX)` por lo que entiendo se esta perdiendo en el subtring ya que me arroja el siguiente error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: El índice y la longitud deben hacer referencia
>   a una ubicación en la cadena.

La iteración donde rompe es en la **43676** la longitud de la subcadena es **2** y la longitud de la cadena es **43677** Es lógico que rompa, pues le estoy diciendo que longitud dos y ya solo le queda un caracter. Aquí tengo ahora otra duda, pues al registro de base de datos le estoy quitando dos caracteres al principio viene con **0x** no se porque la base de datos lo tiene así yo se los quite porque **x** no entra en el hexadecimal, pero no se si eso este afectando en la composición de la cadena.

¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

Comment: No requieres ninguna librería externa. Lo único que debes hacer es hacer un `SELECT` a ese campo, leerlo en C# con un `reader`, y luego invocar al método `File.WriteAllBytes` pasando como parámetro la ruta donde desees guardar el archivo. Intenta hacer lo que te digo, pon tus intentos y prometo apoyarte en las dudas que vayan saliendo :D

Comment: Vale, gracias empezare por ahí. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Les comento, que la respuesta de @Flxtr me dio un indicio pero aún tenia problemas con `File.WriteAllBytes` ya que me pide un arreglo de **bytes** como argumento y no encontraba como convertirlo a un arreglo de bytes. Para lo cual lo termine haciendo de esta manera:

```
 foreach (DataRow rowDoc in Docdata.Rows)
     {
      BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
      MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
      bf.Serialize(ms, rowDoc["EC_ElementContent"]);
      var exp = ms.ToArray();
      Console.WriteLine(path_child + @"\" + rowDoc["E_Name"]);
      File.WriteAllBytes(path_child + @"\" + rowDoc["E_Name"], exp);
     }
```

Donde creo un objeto de la clase `BinaryFormatter` y uno de la clase `MemoryStream` para utilizar `Serialize` y finalmente ese objeto lo convierto a un arreglo para poder crear el documento.

Answer (score 0):

Para la generación de documentos en alguna carpeta, basta con seleccionarlos de la base de datos e invocar directamente al método [`File.WriteAllBytes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx), pasando como parámetros, el nombre del archivo y los bytes que se desean escribir en el archivo.

Tomando como un supuesto, que la información se desea escribir los documentos en la carpeta `C:\Documentos\`, tienen una extensión PDF y el nombre del archivo se encuentra en una columna llamada `FileName`:

`using System.IO;`

```
string connectionString = //Aquí va tu cadena de conexión
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
{
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 10000;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT FileName, Imagen FROM TuTablaConImagenes WITH(NOLOCK)";
        conn.Open();
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                try
                {
                    File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\Documentos\\" + reader["FileName"].ToString() + ".pdf", (byte[])reader["Imagen"]);
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    //Manejo de la excepción cuando el guardado falló
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Toma en cuenta que la escritura de archivos debe ser una carpeta que no sea de sistema, que tengas permisos así como también espacio en disco.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta me oriento por donde comenzar, pero lo he resuelto.